# AngularJS directive get inner element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got next directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .directive('inner', inner);

    function inner () {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link: linkFunc
        };

        function linkFunc (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
})();
```

And HTML:

```
<span inner>{{vm.number}}</span>
```

How can I access vm.number's value in linkFunc? I need to take value exactly from content of the span tag.

Comment: can you please provide the plunker for this?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/aaDSsj8prMJakqiR8OTy?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways you can do this but here are the 2 most common ways:

## ngModel

You could use `ng-model` like so in your template:

```
<span inner ng-model="vm.number">{{vm.number}}</span>
```

In your directive you require the `ngModel` where you can pull its value:

```
.directive( 'inner', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
            var val = ngModel.$modelValue
        }
    }
})
```

## declare isolate scope properties

```
<span inner="vm.number">{{vm.number}}</span>

.directive( 'inner', function(){
    return {
        scope: { inner:'=' } ,
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
            var val = $scope.inner
        }
    }
})
```

---

Some less common ways:

## use $parse service to get the value

Using the template again:

```
<span inner="vm.number">{{vm.number}}</span>
```

Let's assume you're going to Firstly you'll need to inject the `$parse` service in your directive's definition.  Then inside your `link` function do the following:

```
var val = $parse(attrs.inner)
```

## inherited scope for read only

I don't recommend this, because depending on how you defined your directive's scope option, things might get out of sync:

1. **isolate** (aka isolated) scopes will not inherit that value and `vm.number` will probably throw an undefined reference error because `vm` is undefined in most cases.
2. **inherited scope** will inherit the initial value from the parent scope but could diverge during run-time.
3. **no scope** will be the only case where it will stay in sync since the directive's `$scope` reference is the same scope present in the expression `{{vm.number}}`

Again I stress this is probably not the best option here.  I'd only recommend this if you are suffering performance issues from a large number of repeated elements or large number of bindings.  More on the directive's scope options - https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/14/angular-directive-scope/

Comment: I was interested in the opportunity to take exactle content, without attributes (to avoid copies in code). But as you mentioned, it is impossible. I would prefer 'declare isolate scope properties', because it allows to pass function's result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, In Angular directive, `Link` function can do almost everything `controller` can.

To make it very simple, we use one of them most of the time.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {

          $scope.number = 5;

    }).directive('inner', function () {

      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var number = scope.number;
          console.log(number);
        }
      }

    });
```

Inside html :

```
<div inner ng-model="number">{{number}}</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/YbXYpNtu7S3wc0zuBw3u?p=preview

In order to take value from HTML, Angular provides `ng-model` directive which is works on two way data binding concepts.

There are other ways which is already explain by @jusopi :)

cheers!

Comment: I wanna take value from controller to directive, not vice versa.